# to crow in French, plus cock-a-doodle-doo in French

Tags: vocabulaire

In English to crow is a verb to describe sounds roosters make.

1) What is that in French?

2) What exactly do roosters say in French? (how does it sound to French people)

Thank you.

Comment: Just use a dictionary. [Verbe : crow  Chanter (pour un coq)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/crow).

Comment: That's an information you could easily find without asking a new question. I googled "cock-a-doodle-do in french" and in 5 seconds I found [this.](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/cock-a-doodle-doo)

Answer (score 2):

Selon [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_cris_d'animaux) :

- Verbe

  - chanter, coqueliner, coqueriquer
- conjugué

  - il chante, coqueline : au point du jour, coquerique
- le cri

  - le chant, coquelinement, coqueriquement

[Les onomatopées dans plusieurs langues.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq)

Comment: Some seems very scarce and uncommon now ! (Coqueliner, or coqueriquer) ça ne doit plus beaucoup se dire... Add to this the very famous "Cocorico". "Le coq fait/pousse/émet/chante.. son cocorico"